# Tkinter frame with scrollbars cutting off some data

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to populate a Tk frame with checkboxes.  I'm able to list them on the frame and make the list scroll, however, after a certain number of items being listed (which seems to vary depending on the data being output), the list stops displaying.  I know the other items are technically there, as I can tab up and down from the last item I can view, yet for whatever reason the full list doesn't display properly.  Any ideas?

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
from AutoScrollbar import AutoScrollbar

selectRoot = Tk()
selectRoot.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

selectRoot.title("Portal Creator - Select Clients")

vscrollbar = AutoScrollbar(selectRoot)
vscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
hscrollbar = AutoScrollbar(selectRoot, orient=HORIZONTAL)
hscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
canvas = Canvas(selectRoot, yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=hscrollbar.set)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
hscrollbar.config(command=canvas.xview)

selectRoot.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
selectRoot.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame = Frame(canvas)
frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=2)
frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

clientList = []
clientListItems = {}
rowCounter = 0



for client in xrange(0,3000):


    checkInt = IntVar()

    clientListItems['clientCheck'] = Checkbutton(frame, text=client, variable=checkInt)

    clientListItems['clientCheck'].grid(row=rowCounter, column=0, sticky=W)

    clientListItems['checkInt'] = checkInt

    clientList.append(clientListItems.copy())

    rowCounter += 1

canvas.create_window(1, 1, anchor=NW, window=frame)
frame.update_idletasks()
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

selectRoot.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're trying to display 3000 checkboxes? How do you expect a user to actually use an interface like that?

Comment: Yes, I want to display approximately that many checkboxes. It's only so we have a list of everything in front of us, while we'll only be selecting a few options (from an alphabetically sorted list) at a time. I'm not a professional developer, this is just a project to automate some repetitive upcoming work, so I'll  be the only one using this (together with someone from our administrative assistance team). If you could suggest an easy way to fix this by modifying what I'm trying to do, I'd be open to it. Thanks!